Managing StreamChatClient Initialization and Connection with Riverpod: Architecture Advice
Background:
I’m using StreamChat in my Flutter app. The documentation mentions that the StreamChatClient should only be initialized once and client.connectUser() should only be called once to avoid issues with multiple WebSocket connections. To implement this, I’m using Riverpod for state management and the repository pattern to manage the client.
Current Approach:
•    I have a StreamChatClient provider.
•    I inject this client into ChatsRepository through a provider.
•    I also have a ConnectionStatusProvider that listens to the connection status from the ChatsRepository.

However, I’m seeing chats_repository: chatsRepositoryProvider onAddListener being called twice. This seems to occur when I watch it in both MainApp and GoRouterProvider.
Questions:
1.    Does having multiple listeners on a provider imply that I’m creating multiple instances of StreamChatClient? If so, how can I structure this differently to ensure a single client instance?
2.    Is it correct to call final `client = ref.watch(streamChatClientProvider); `within ChatsRepositoryProvider? Or is there a better way to manage the client injection to avoid multiple initializations?
3.    Am I correctly monitoring connection status in ConnectionStatusProvider?

Relevant Code Snippets:
chat_repository.dart:
class ChatsRepository {
  ChatsRepository(this._client);
  final StreamChatClient _client;
  // final Ref ref;

  StreamChatClient get client => _client;

  ConnectionStatus get connectionStatus => _client.wsConnectionStatus;

  Stream<ConnectionStatus> get connectionStatusStream =>
      _client.wsConnectionStatusStream;

  Future<void> connectUser() async {
  try {
      await _client.connectUser(user, token);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error connecting user: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> disconnectUser() async {/*------*/}

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
StreamChatClient streamChatClient(StreamChatClientRef ref) {
  final client = StreamChatClient();

  ref.onDispose(() {
    client.dispose();
  });
  ref.onAddListener(() =>
      debugPrint('chats_repository: chatsRepositoryProvider onAddListener'));
  ref.onDispose(
      () => debugPrint('chats_repository: chatsRepositoryProvider onDispose'));

  return client;
}

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
ChatsRepository chatsRepository(ChatsRepositoryRef ref) {
  final client = ref.watch(streamChatClientProvider);

  ref.onDispose(() {
    client.dispose();
  });

  return ChatsRepository(client);
}

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Stream<ConnectionStatus> connectionStatus(ConnectionStatusRef ref) {
  final client = ref.watch(chatsRepositoryProvider);
  return client.connectionStatusStream;
}

main.dart:
void main() async {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final goRouter = ref.watch(goRouterProvider);
    debugPrint('watching streamChatClientProvider in MainApp');
    final client = ref.watch(streamChatClientProvider);

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: goRouter,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return StreamChat(
          client: client,
          streamChatThemeData: streamChatThemeData,
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      title: 'App',
      theme: theme,
      restorationScopeId: 'app',
    );
  }
}

app_router.dart:
@riverpod
GoRouter goRouter(GoRouterRef ref) {
  debugPrint('watching chatRepositoryProvider in goRouter');
  final chatRepository = ref.watch(chatsRepositoryProvider);
  final client = chatRepository.client;

  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/chats',
    redirect: (context, state) async {
      // making this call here is temporary until i can find the right place for it
      final token = client.devToken('xxxxxxxxxxx').rawValue;
      if (client.wsConnectionStatus != ConnectionStatus.connected) {
        debugPrint('Connecting user');
        await client.connectUser(
          User(id: '123456', name: 'Test'),
          token,
        );
      }
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          path: '/chats',
          name: AppRoute.chats.name,
          builder: (context, state) => Chats(),
        ),
    ]
  );
}

